# Append data.table totals row through chain instead of rbindlist?

Tags: r, data.table, summary

Exactly as the title says - I have the following style data:

```
library(data.table)
DT = data.table(name =LETTERS[seq( from = 1, to = 10 )],x=seq(from=1,to=10),y=seq(from=11,to=20),z=seq(from=21,to=30))
setkey(DT,name)
DT[, `:=`(xy = x / y, xz = x / z, yz = y / z)][,
    c(name = "Total", lapply(.SD, sum), lapply(.SD2, mean)), list(.SDcols=2:4,.SD2cols=5:7)][,
    rbind(DT, .SD)]

    name  x  y  z         xy         xz        yz
 1:    A  1 11 21 0.09090909 0.04761905 0.5238095
 2:    B  2 12 22 0.16666667 0.09090909 0.5454545
 3:    C  3 13 23 0.23076923 0.13043478 0.5652174
 4:    D  4 14 24 0.28571429 0.16666667 0.5833333
 5:    E  5 15 25 0.33333333 0.20000000 0.6000000
 6:    F  6 16 26 0.37500000 0.23076923 0.6153846
 7:    G  7 17 27 0.41176471 0.25925926 0.6296296
 8:    H  8 18 28 0.44444444 0.28571429 0.6428571
 9:    I  9 19 29 0.47368421 0.31034483 0.6551724
10:    J 10 20 30 0.50000000 0.33333333 0.6666667
```

I've seen that it would possible to create a vector like,

```
DT["Total" ,] <- c(colSums(DT[2:4]),colMeans(DT[5]))
```

or to use an `rbindlist`, however I'm specifically interested in the possibility of completing this through chaining. Is it possible to do this through means of a multiple `.SDcol` function as I paraphrased above?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by chaining, but `DT[, c(name = "Total", lapply(.SD, sum), xy = mean(xy)), .SDcols=x:z][, rbind(DT, .SD)]` works, just barely.

Comment: the question is, why do you want to do this? Why not just use `margin.table`?

Comment: @Frank - this is perfect. Exactly what I was looking for. And chaining as in you can add this immediately after the previous `data.table` selection block and it works continuously. (ie. `DT[,xy := x/y][, c(name = "Total", lapply(.SD, sum), xy = mean(xy)), .SDcols=x:z][, rbind(DT, .SD)]`

@MichaelChirico - I considered margins but I do not need the row summaries, just the column summaries. I'll have to research a bit but is it possible to do means/etc with margin calculations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, you can chain like `DT[...][...]`. In the OP's case:

```
DT[,xy := x/y][, 
  c(name = "Total", lapply(.SD, sum), xy = mean(xy)), .SDcols=x:z][, 
  rbind(DT, .SD)]
```

However, this is a very fragile construction and hard to work with for editing or debugging.

I would at least break it into...

```
DT[,xy := x/y]
DT[, 
  c(name = "Total", lapply(.SD, sum), xy = mean(xy)), .SDcols=x:z][, 
  rbind(DT, .SD)]
```

I think it's worth pointing out that adding a summary row like this is typically counterproductive unless you're done working with the data and want to print or browse it.

Comment: I made a slight addition to my original question - because this works for the one variable but I'm wondering if it's possible to apply your answer to multiple summary functions in multiple `.SDcol` blocks?

Comment: @gscott Nope. You can probably make `.SDcols` consist of the combined set and then do `c(lapply(.SD[, 1:3], sum), lapply(.SD[, 4:6], mean))` or similar, though.